# Magento2: How to get additional-fieldsets for custom address form(Not in checkout page)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0

[image]

In a custom template phtml I initialized an UI component

```
<div id="shipping-component" data-bind="scope:'address-list'">
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
                "#shipping-component": {
                    "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                       "components": {
                            "address-list": {
                                "component": "Vendor_Namespace/js/view/shipping-address/list"
                            },
                            "shipping": {
                                 "component": "Vendor_Namespace/js/view/shipping"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            </script>
            <script>
                window.checkoutConfig = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getCheckoutConfig()); ?>;
                // Create aliases for customer.js model from customer module
                window.isCustomerLoggedIn = window.checkoutConfig.isCustomerLoggedIn;
                window.customerData = window.checkoutConfig.customerData;
            </script>
        </div>
```

In list.html I call

```
<div class="new-address">
            <!-- ko template: 'Vendor_Namespace/shipping/address' --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
```

In address.html template I called a shipping-address form

```
<!-- Inline address form -->
    <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form' --><!-- /ko -->
```

And in form template we have

```
<div id="shipping-new-address-form" class="fieldset address">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('additional-fieldsets') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
</div>
```

But seem like I didn't get any getRegion('additional-fieldsets') and template for my custom form. Any help?

Like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your html template structure is "messy". But I have a hint for you. Try to add `$parent` reference to `getRegion`: `$parent.getRegion('additional-fieldsets')`. Not test yet.